# NSCalendar firstWeekday depending on location issue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, date, nscalendar

Is it possible to get firstWeekday depending on location. For instance, in USA it should say Sunday. In Russia it should say Monday.

Edit: `[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]` always says `1`, but for Russia it should say `2`

Comment: Did you try calling setLocale on the calendar?

Comment: you are right, that helped. Right the answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. The calendar **shouldn't** return 1 in USA and 2 in Russia.

First of all, the device never knows in which country it is located. It takes everything from the `Regional Settings` in the Device Settings. The regional settings are then accessible through `NSLocale`, e.g. `en-US` means that `USA English` settings should be used, including the first week day.

In general, you should just use `[NSLocale defaultLocale]`, which is implicitly set on `NSCalendar`, `NSDateFormatter` and similar classes. If you want to simulate the behavior with different language/regional settings, just change them in Device Settings.